# Embed JavascriptCore in C application

Tags: c, javascriptcore

I'm trying to find information on how to embed JavascriptCore in a C project. It's easy to find guides for both V8 and SpiderMonkey, but near impossible to find for JSC. Does anyone know where to look?

I'd rather not embed V8 as it's C++, and i heard SpiderMonkey's API was horrible.

Comment: I am trying to find a full example(s) for JavaScriptCore but all I can find is this: http://uselessbyte.blogspot.com/2009/12/adding-custom-javascript-bindings-to.html I guess you have found this one too :) Have you got any more?

Comment: Actually, this is alot more than I found :P

Comment: So, how did it end up for you? Did you use V8?

Comment: Haven't come to a conclusion yet, looking at other options (namely python).

Comment: I ended up using Mono, as it had no external dependencies...

Comment: This link http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore says that JavaScriptCore is a part of WebKit.  Here is a link to the JavaScriptCore page within WebKit site http://www.webkit.org/projects/javascript/index.html.

Comment: @RichardChambers write an answer with that (including the last link) and I'll accept it :-) It's not a guide of any kind, but knowing to compile WebKit and use it's JSC-api should suffice.

Comment: Wow, you found one of my really old blog posts. Does this method still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link for the [JavaScriptCore web page](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore) says that JavaScriptCore is a part of WebKit. Here is a link to the [JavaScriptCore page within WebKit site](http://webkit.org/projects/javascript/index.html).

This [wikipedia topic on webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) mentions history including a bit of information about JavaScriptCore.

Here is some [information about web kit from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html).  And here is an article about [new developments with WebKit Javascript](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/12/03/01/new_low_level_javascript_interpreter_to_boost_webkit_performance_more_than_200.html).

And this looks like [information for webkit with Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html).

And here is a test engine, the [SunSpider JavaScript benchmark](http://www.webkit.org/perf/sunspider/sunspider.html).

And you might find this slide show, [Hacking Webkit & its JavaScript Engines](http://www.slideshare.net/senchainc/hacking-webkit-its-javascript-engines) helpful.